# extract folder id from url ios

Tags: ios

I want to extract folder id from this url

https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.1ee916c3057a1eaf.1EE916C3057A1EAF!2204/files/wpid-full-hd-wallpapers-1080p-citimortgage-1.jpg?suppress_response_codes=true&overwrite=false

Is it possible?

Comment: Use `NSString` substring methods to do so.

Comment: what exactly from above url is folder id according to you? ie 1ee916c3057a1eaf.1EE916C3057A1EAF!2204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
NSString *url = @"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.1ee916c3057a1eaf.1EE916C3057A1EAF!2204/files/wpid-full-hd-wallpapers-1080p-citimortgage-1.jpg?suppress_response_codes=true&overwrite=false";
NSArray *splitStr = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *folderId = [splitStr objectAtIndex:4];
NSLog(@"folderId = %@", folderId);
```

out put: `folderId = folder.1ee916c3057a1eaf.1EE916C3057A1EAF!2204`

Comment: don’t you think url might change then your logic will not worl at all.

Comment: ur code is working but my problem is i am extracting the url by using this method                                           NSString *myfile=[error.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSErrorFailingURLKey"];
    NSLog(@"myfile is %@",myfile);

Comment: `[splitStr objectAtIndex:4]` is a static value, and may change in future.

Comment: yes it hard code. But in one API, location of a resource in path parameter may still not change

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. `NSString` offers the method `- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange`.

You can create a `NSRange` using `NSMakeRange`. So, assuming you folder ID starts at the `n-th` index of your string and is of length `l`, you can retrieve the folder ID like so:

`NSString *folderID = [url substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(n, l)];`